# Overview of free software licenses (for dummies)

Tags: open-source, licensing

Does anyone know of a reference that explains the different open-source licenses in easily understandable, non-legalese terms?

Specifically I'm looking for information about what it means to me when I'd like to use and redistribute some (open-source) library with my own products, e.g. something like this:

- a library distributed under license X

  - can be modified, used and redistributed without restrictions, even in commercial, closed-source products
- a library distributed under license Y

  - may not be modified, but can be redistributed with a commercial, closed-source products
  - it is required to mention the fact that a product makes use of that library (e.g. by adding some license file, etc)
- a library distributed under license Z

  - may only be used by projects which are also distributed under the same license

Comment: Lots of dupes including http://stackoverflow.com/questions/236699/what-open-source-license-to-choose. To see all the questions on this topic, google for "site:stackoverflow.com open source licenses"

Comment: GitHub created a domain for this reason, it can be found here: http://choosealicense.com/licenses/ (source: https://github.com/blog/1530-choosing-an-open-source-license)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's a list there, with a FAQ: http://www.fsf.org/licensing/licenses/

In your case, I think that X=public domain, Y=some commercial licenses, Z=GPL
(modified BSD is similar to Y, but you are allowed to modify them).

The licenses themselves are fairly readable.

Answer (score 28):

This is going to be a big grave dig, but after reading this question I can't help but to slip this link here:

http://www.tldrlegal.com

^Lookup any software license summarized in plain english (What you can, cannot and must do).